# Indefinite integral : $\int \frac{dx}{(1+x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am stuck in this exercise of calculus about solving this indefinite integral, so I would like some help from your part:

> $$\int \frac{dx}{(1+x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please share some thought/give some context. What have you done? Where did this problem occur? ... It will help others to help you better.

Comment: try it with $$x=\sin(t)$$

Comment: @mickep I found it from a friend of mine and so we decided to ask on the website

Comment: @AhmadouNdongoÇam the integral is with a plus or a minus sine?

Comment: @rafaelWagner it is with a plus sign

Comment: Don't forget to check out my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \sinh u$. Then the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \int \frac{\cosh u}{\cosh^3 u}\mathrm du = \int\operatorname{sech}^2 u\,\mathrm du$$

Now, $\operatorname{sech}^2 u$ is the derivative of a well-known hyperbolic function. Can you spot it?

---

**Previous answer, when the question had a minus in the denominator**

Let $x = \sin u$. Then we have
$$\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1-x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \int \frac{\cos u}{\cos^3 u}\mathrm du = \int\sec^2 u\,\mathrm du$$

Now, $\sec^2 u$ is the derivative of a well-known trigonometric function. Can you spot it?

Then, if you desire to remove trigonometric functions, recall the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ and you're done.

Comment: "Trigonometric function" is the more standard term.

Comment: Where goniometric came from?

Comment: @eyeballfrog You're right. In my native language we actually differentiate between the two, but apparently that's not what happens in English. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: The user changed the $(1-x^2)$ for $(1 + x^2)$

Comment: I made a mistake; the denominator is $(1+x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: @AhmadouNdongoÇam Well it's basically the same thing, you just have to substitute an hyperbolic function.

Comment: @rubik Would you please say how; I do not understand

Comment: @AhmadouNdongoÇam Check it now.

Comment: @rubik Thanks for the edit . Is it f(x) = tanh x ? Or?

Comment: @AhmadouNdongoÇam Yes, that's the one. To be more precise you obtain $\tanh u$, and when you substitute back you have $\tanh(\operatorname{arcsinh} x)$, which you can simplify back with some hyperbolic trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 1):

We have $t>0$.

Recall that

$$\int\frac1{(t^2-x^2)^{1/2}}\ dx=\arcsin\left(\frac xt\right)+c_1$$

Take the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$ to get

$$\int\frac{-t}{(t^2-x^2)^{3/2}}\ dx=\frac{-x}{|t|\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}+c_2$$

Setting $t=1$ and simplifying, we reach

$$\int\frac1{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}\ dx=\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+c_3$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$ and use change of variables.

**Hint 2:**

> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\tanh(x)\right) =\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}\right) = \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)}\left(\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)\right) = \text{sech}^2(x)$$